# Encapsulation and inner classes

Tags: c++, visibility, inner-classes, private-members

The current program I'm working on has a lot of inner classes. Since many of these inner classes are private and not accessible from outside the parent class, I'm thinking of simplifying things a bit and just making all the private inner class's members public, as below:

```
    class Game {
    public:
    .
    .
    .

    private:

        class Monster {
        public:
            Monster(string qu, string an, string desc, int time_lim);
            ~Monster();
            int Interact (Monster a);
            void CountDown(int time_limit);
        //Is this ok, or must the following variables be private?
            string q;
            string a;
            string description;
            int time_limit;
        };
  }
```

I know that as a general rule member variables should never be declared public. However, it seems like overkill to include getters and setters for an inner class like Monster. Is the code above acceptable?

Thanks!

Comment: Getters and setters are evil anyway.  If you want open access within the class, what you want is a struct.  "Public" is a bit of a misnomer anyway, considering the type itself is not visible outside of the `Game` class.

Comment: Making private inner classes 'open' is perfectly OK. In the code above though, I'd question whether Monster should be an inner class at all. Looks like a class that can stand in it's own right.

Comment: @cHao - "Getters and setters are evil anyway" - No they are not. They enable one to control access to the data. It enables one to hide away the implementation details.

Comment: @EdHeal: Unless you use them very sparingly (which hardly anyone ever does), they actually *expose* implementation details.  Add a getter and setter for every member variable, and suddenly the innards of your class are part of the API.  It's false data hiding; even if you hide the variable behind accessors, it still has to be there (or a translation mechanism provided).  You can't significantly change functionality at that point without a breaking change to the API.

Comment: If you want those variables to be in public interface, then you will soon find out that you want also to have their types to be also available outside.

Comment: @cHao - Eh? You have the minimum. Some of the getters/setters may hae to do some computation. Dunno what projects you have worked on but all the ones I have worked on (some are very large) have only one or two at most per class. Also there use enables one to have read only variables and consistency between two member variables

Comment: @cHao they are useful especially getters when they are const, client of such api can only read its value

Comment: @EdHeal: I've noticed more of a problem with it in Java and PHP.  I'd rather not see it in C++ too.  :P

Comment: In java you dont have a notion of const getter, they asked sun for const like modifier in java for a very long with no luck.

Comment: @marcin_j: If they get a value *that the client should know about*, they can be useful.  (They're still evil, but sometimes they're the lesser evil.)  Any value that's specific to the implementation, though, should not be visible at all, even if it's read-only.